# Error /w OPENQUERY access error in SQL Server create procedure. Possible to create anyway?

Tags: sql-server, procedure, openquery

Basic idea is I need to create a procedure, but I don't have access to the `OPENQUERY` linked server table so it errors out stating user does not have `SELECT` access. The idea is I'm trying to create the stored procedure and will have someone who does have access run it.

I've tried `TRY/CATCH` and that still provided the same issue. Is it due to the `OPENQUERY`? Any other way to ignore the error? Not sure why wrapping it in `TRY/CATCH` doesn't seem to ignore the error?

Basic code:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY(SERVER_NAME,'SELECT ABC FROM ABC.DEF')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: `TRY..CATCH` does nothing because resolution errors like these are part of the compilation process; your query doesn't even get to run because SQL Server can't determine an execution plan. Bottom line, you can't create the sproc if you don't have access. Why is this a problem, though -- why wouldn't you have a privileged account like a sysadmin/DB admin create the stored procedure in the first place?

Comment: We won't get into the crazieness that is our DBA teams at my work. The admins do create the proc in live production, this is just a dev area. I was able to work around this by wrapping the statements in EXEC('statement') as that doesn't calculate it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to wrap the OPENQUERY /w EXEC instead which worked around this issue.